# Packages for developing static web sites in Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, pharo, visualworks

What would be good (cross Smalltalk, mantained, documented) web frameworks or packages (in terms of fewer things to learn/adapt) to use for implementing a static web site with really few forms? .i.e. : a search box and a contact form. I have no "model" or application behind, so I'm not searching for CMS or web application capabilities.

There is any example or simple script of a static web site developed in any web frameworks? please I'm NOT interested in counter or 'Hello World' examples. The examples I've seen from Seaside looks too complicated, too many nested blocks with the "programmatic HTML" and the ones I've seen from AIDA needed a model object, couldn't figure how to get something working without a model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All Smalltalk web-servers (Zinc, Kom, and Swazoo) can serve static files. If you take Pharo 1.3, Zinc is already pre-loaded. Just look at the code, tests and comments and you should get a server running in no time.

Answer (score 0):

All Smalltalk web-servers (Zinc, Kom, and Swazoo) can serve static files. If you take Pharo 1.3, Zinc is already pre-loaded. Just look at the code, tests and comments and you should get a server running in no time. (via [Lukas Renggli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82303/lukas-renggli))

[Taking some performance hit, you can have Seaside serve content as though it was static.](http://onsmalltalk.com/clean-urls-in-seaside)